# How to stop Android 7.1 app shortcuts from ignoring Activity launchMode?

Tags: android

I have a static app shortcut declared like so:

```
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/shortcut"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/downloads"
    android:shortcutId="downloads"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/downloads"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/downloads">

    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetClass="com.colinrtwhite.test.activity.DownloadsActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.colinrtwhite.test"/>
</shortcut>
```

and it is declared in my AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.DownloadsActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes), the `singleTask` launch mode is supposed to re-use existing instances of an Activity and pass new intents through the onNewIntent method. However, if I have an existing instance of DownloadsActivity and tap the app shortcut to launch it, it will destroy then recreate the Activity.

My question: how do I force the app shortcut to re-use an existing instance of my Activity and not restart it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using static shortcut, according to documentation

> Static shortcuts cannot have custom intent flags. The first intent of a static shortcut will always have FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK set. This means, when the app is already running, all the existing activities will be destroyed when a static shortcut is launched.

Also according to the same part

> Dynamic shortcuts can be published with any set of Intent flags. Typically, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is specified, possibly along with other flags;

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html, part Shortcut Intents.

Comment: Hmm so it looks like using a dynamic shortcut might fix my problem. I'll try it out later tonight and report back (and accept your answer if it fixes the issue). Thanks!